# Paperclip and RMagick: no decode delegate for this image format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rmagick

**Why is ImageMagick unable to open my Paperclip upload?**

I need to be able to run a few checks on it.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ATTACHMENT_STYLES = lambda do |attachment|
    if is_something?(attachment.instance)
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
  ATTACHMENT_PROCESSORS = lambda { |attachment| is_something?(attachment.instance) ? [:other_processor] : [:thumbnail] }

  ...

  def self.is_something?(attachment)
    file = Magick::ImageList.new(attachment)

    ...
  end
end
```

**But why am I getting this?**

```
Magick::ImageMagickError in TopicsController#create
no decode delegate for this image format `0x00000004e3cc50>' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544
Extracted source (around line #20):
file = Magick::ImageList.new(attachment)

app/models/photo.rb:20:in `new'
app/models/photo.rb:20:in `is_something?'
app/models/photo.rb:3:in `block in <class:Photo>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're assigning a value in the if block:

```
true if file.attachment_content_type = /gif/ && file.size
```

If you're trying to match it against the regex, you actually want to use `=~` like this:

```
true if file.attachment_content_type =~ /gif/ && file.size
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that observation! However the problem still persists unfortunately.